# How to prevent Crashlytics from logging crashes during development in Android

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

While developing the app sometimes it crashes, and It's known crash while development, It unnecessarily sends mail to the client that some Trending stability issues in the app.

So I want to know if any method is there to stop logging while the development journey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crashlytics gives you the option to [opt in or out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting) from sending crash reports. You could use this in your code to prevent sending crash reports during development.

For this you could set the `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` property in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to `false`.

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

With this option you can then re-enable Crashlytics data collection when running the release version:

```java
if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG){
   FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
}
```

Or a similar option could be disabling Crashlytics data collection only when running the debug build. In this case, the the manifest property is not required.

```java
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
   FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gerardo, can <meta-data> automatically disable for debug mode and enable it for Release, or do I need to do it manually every time true/false while building APK?

Comment: You can set the <meta-data> property to "false" in your app ( for both Debug and Release) and then override this value by calling "setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)" programmatically when running the Release version.

Comment: In which file I need to call this "setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)"?

Comment: You can call this anywhere in your code. For this case you can put it in the onCreate method of the MainActivity so crashes start getting tracked early on.

Comment: If I mention this in MainActivity, So It will track only for MainActivity or whole app?

Comment: It will track the whole app. This method is only for instructing Crashlytics to start or stop collecting data. This is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting

Answer (score 1):

you can disable uploading of mapping file and symbols in debug build:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            firebaseCrashlytics {
               mappingFileUploadEnabled true
               nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
        debug {
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                // If you don't need crash reporting for your debug build,
                // you can speed up your build by disabling mapping file uploading.
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This configuration change will prevent Crashlytics from uploading symbol or mapping files for debug builds. While this will make the build faster, it does not prevent Crashlytics from reporting crashes in debug builds, which is what the OP is looking for. Without the mapping or symbol files, the crash reports will be unreadable as Crashlytics cannot deobfuscate or symbolicate them.

Comment: you're right. then the option is to disable reporting either by adding meta-data tag to AndroidManifest.xml for debug build only or disable reporting in code by checking build configuration and calling 
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false) for debug build. But I think 1st way is easier and better.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?hl=en&authuser=0&platform=android#enable-reporting